# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I know this is an error that has been explained at length in numerous other questions. However it still seems to be a topic for debate as its highly subjective. I have two questions;

**How detrimental is this error?**

I've been working on an app that requires a custom `UINavigationController`. I create a false root that allows me to change the perceived root more easily. To create this affect I 'pop' to the false root then immediately 'push' the new one. Like this;

```
[self popToViewController:self.fakeRootViewController animated:NO];
[self pushViewController:newRootViewController animated:NO];
```

I've been working with this for weeks. I've not had any unexpected side effect or any negative reactions. So to sum up; Do I need to worry about this error?

**Is there a better way?**

Having explained my situation my second question is simply how else can I set the rootViewController?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also push the newRootViewController in the fakeRootViewController's
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: Interesting idea. I hadn't contemplated using methods in the `fakeRoot ViewController` at the moment its just a standard `UIViewController`. I'll give it a go. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. However This solution didn't fix the problem. I've reverted back to my original set up as it's less classes to worry about. Never the less thank you all the same.